# Buenas tardes, tengo un problema con esta función

Tags: java, java-8

**Mi objetivo es que en la tabla de aprobados me devuelva el nombre de los aprobados, he intentado lo siguiente, funciona si los alumnos que han aprobado son consecutivos en la tabla, pero si por ejemplo el alumno 0 con nombre Luis tiene un 8, el alumno 1 con nombre Juan tiene un 3 y el alumno 2 con nombre Franma tiene un 7 me da error... ¿Cómo podría arreglar ese error? **

```
public class p1 {

    static void aprobados (String tA[], double tN[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i <= tN.length-1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumn@ "+(i+1));
            tA[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    
        String aprobados [] = new String [0];
        int longitud = aprobados.length;
    
        String alumno;
        double nota;

        for (int i = 0; i < tN.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce la nota del alumn@ "+(tA[i])); 
            tN[i] = sc.nextDouble();

            if (tN[i] >= 5) {
                alumno = tA[i];
                nota = i;
                longitud++;
                aprobados = Arrays.copyOf(aprobados, longitud);
                aprobados[i] = alumno;
            }
        }
    
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tA));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tN));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aprobados));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("¿Cuántos alumnos hay en la clase?");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
    
        String tablaAlumnos[] = new String [n];
        double tablaNotas[] = new double [n];
    
        aprobados(tablaAlumnos, tablaNotas);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te muestra es un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` y esto ocurre cuando sobrepasamos el limite de un `array`

Tu problema lo tienes aquí:

```
 String aprobados [] = new String [0];
 int longitud = aprobados.length;
 . . .
 longitud++;
 aprobados = Arrays.copyOf(aprobados, longitud);
```

Con tan solo declarar un nuevo `array` para guardar los alumnos donde su nota sea `>=5` es suficiente para tu ejercicio.

```
String aprobados[] = new String[tA.length];
```

Variables como nota, longitud etc no te son necesarias.

Te dejo tu ejemplo completo para que veas como quedaría:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void aprobados(String tA[], double tN[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String aprobados[] = new String[tA.length];

        for (int i = 0; i <= tN.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del alumn@ " + (i + 1));
            tA[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tN.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce la nota del alumn@ " + (tA[i]));
            tN[i] = sc.nextDouble();

            if (tN[i] >= 5) {
                aprobados[i] = tA[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tA));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tN));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aprobados));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("¿Cuántos alumnos hay en la clase?");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        String tablaAlumnos[] = new String[n];
        double tablaNotas[] = new double[n];

        aprobados(tablaAlumnos, tablaNotas);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
¿Cuántos alumnos hay en la clase?
 3
Introduce el nombre del alumn@ 1
 luis
Introduce el nombre del alumn@ 2
 juan
Introduce el nombre del alumn@ 3
 fran
Introduce la nota del alumn@ luis
 8
Introduce la nota del alumn@ juan
 3
Introduce la nota del alumn@ fran
 7

[luis, juan, fran]
[8.0, 3.0, 7.0]
[luis, null, fran]
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ^^

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido :)